# Shell Script to install software & configure network

Tags: scripts

Hey, I wanted to know, how to, after a fresh install of Ubuntu, I can install all essential softwares(vlc, apache, MySQL, PHP, java, Netbeansetc) using a shell script.

Also I wanted that same shell script to configure my static network IP including Address, Gateway, netmask & DNS server IP for IPv4...
Possible ?

Not impossible, right?

Comment: you'll get more viewers (and possibly some answers) for your question if you add a tag for linux. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this about a week ago, because my SSD died and I had to use a LiveCD and I didn't want to repeat steps:

The variables I used should be explanatory:

```
ifconfig eth0 $address netmask $netmask
ip route add default via $gateway
echo "nameserver $dns_server" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

This assumes that the script will be run as root. If not, you need to prepend `sudo` to the first two commands and replace `>` in the third command with `| sudo tee`. Note that these command circumvent Network Manager but it works for me. YMMV

To install programs, you can use apt:

```
apt-get install vlc apache2 mysql-server php5 [other packages here]
```

The next is retrieved from my code on installing software on my LiveCD (root permissions will be asked through sudo):

```
try_install_yes_to_all=false
try_install () {
    # Usage: try_install 'apt_options' package1 package2 ... packageN
    # You'll be prompted whether you want to install a (set of) package(s) or not
    # Y=Yes, N=No, A=All (do not ask in future)
    local opts="$1"
    shift
    if [ $(dpkg -l "$@" 2>/dev/null | grep '^ii' | wc -l) != $# ]; then
        while true; do
            $try_install_yes_to_all || printf 'install %s ? [Y/N/A] ' "$*"
            $try_install_yes_to_all && yn=Y || read yn
            case "$yn" in
                [YyAa])
                    [[ $yn == [Aa] ]] && try_install_yes_to_all=true
                    sudo apt-get install -y $opts "$@"
                    break
                    ;;
                [Nn])
                    break
                    ;;
            esac
        done
    fi
}
# install language packs
try_install '' language-pack-kde-nl language-support-nl
# install Firefox without "Recommended:" packages (like firefox-globalmenu)
try_install '--no-install-recommends' firefox
```

Because certain packages requires a re-login (language packages), I edited the boot options by adding the next line to the kernel options:

```
init=/bin/bash
```

This will load a shell instead of doing a normal boot. Withing that shell, you might need to run `modprobe usb-storage` if your USB stick with the script was not inserted in the system.

Next, mount your partition with the script on it and run it:

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
/mnt/script-to-run
```

Note that you cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or file descriptors. If you need to terminate all programs including the script, issue the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut. If the script is still running, force killing all processes with:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

When the script has completed, unmount the partition:

```
umount /mnt
```

To continue normal booting, run:

```
exec init
```

Answer (score 0):

To use your network connection from the command line, you can use the NetworkManager Command Line Interface (cnetworkmanager) package:

Package information: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/cnetworkmanager

Usage information: http://vidner.net/martin/software/cnetworkmanager/

A sample call that would connect to a network called YOURSSID:

```
cnetworkmanager --connect=YOURSSID
```

As far as installing software from the command line, you can do it using apt-get and apt-cache commands.
First you need to find the exact package names that you want to install (usually including version numbers for the services you've listed).  You can use apt-cache search to find those.  For example:

```
apt-cache search apache
```

Once you've reviewed those results and found the package names, you can install them using apt-get:

```
apt-get install vlc apache mysql etc
```